# ajax natsort() json array sorting

Tags: ajax, json, natsort

I'm **ajaxing an array of images from a file with php opendir function**. It works in-order locally but spits out randomly when I upload it on my server. I thought maybe because I'm not ordering it personally it's doing this. I tried using the **natsort()** on my array before I send it back with **JSON_ENCODE but it doesn't work** because it's returning an object (and it's still in the wrong order just numbered).
I get this locally from console.log():

```
 ["01_cul_project_01.jpg", "02_cor_project_02.jpg", "03_cul_project_03.jpg",...]
```

And this from my server from console.log():

```
 0: "07_cor_project_07.jpg"
 1: "08_cul_project_08.jpg"
 2: "15_cor_project_15.jpg"
 ...
```

Are there any better ways of ordering the array? Any suggestions in how to fix this? Cheers in advance for your help.

EDIT 01 - SOLUTION

Sort the array after JSON callback with javascript:

```
 var blah = array("3","1","5"...);
 blah.sort();
```

Comment: Have you answered this yourself then?

Comment: @Orbling, Yeah was not such a hard one. Probably should not have asked it on here.

Comment: Not a problem, you should just post your answer as an answer and mark it as accepted, to stop further reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the array after JSON callback with javascript:

```
var blah = ["3", "1", "5"...];
blah.sort();
```

gives

```
["1", "2", "3"...]
```